# How to display metainformation for different kinds of time of a file ?

Tags: command-line, files, ls, inode

As far as I know each name within a path, e.g. /name1/name2/name3, is allocated to one inode. This inode is a collection of meta information for each name (file or directory). Some of these informations are time of creation, time of modification, time of last change of status. Now, if I do a "ls -l" for file or dictionary, I can see only one kind of time. What do I need to do to display those different kinds of times as contained in the inode?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `stat` to see more metadata of the file/directory.